# In intellij, how do I specify global libraries with a relative path?

Tags: intellij-idea

I use intellij on my mac and on my pc.

I keep all of my libraries in a folder `C:/kyle/dropbox/lib` on my pc, and in the folder `/Users/kyle/dropbox/lib` on my mac.

How can I specify global libraries in intellij that will work with both paths? Is there a way I can specify the paths to the jars with an environment variable like `$LIB$/.....`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See `Settings` | `Path Variables`, you define path variables on both systems and forget about it, no need to use them explicitly. When project is saved, all actual paths are replaced with path variables in the project files, when project is loaded, variables in project files are replaced with system specific paths according to your settings.

Comment: Sorry to hijack your question - I am in a similar situation; trying to create a global libraries based on path variables. But in the Global Libraries screen, I dont see a way to enter the path variable. A pop up comes to select the library files. Is there any other location where I need to configure global libraries based on path variables?

Comment: How is forcing people to define path variables on every development system the same as using a relative path? How do I use relative paths?

Comment: @StealthRabbi Relative paths will work automatically for all the libraries under the project root. You can't use relative paths for the libraries that reside outside of the project root. Consider using Gradle or Maven if you need to define a lot of external libraries. This will ensure seamless operation for all the developers when IDEA imports the project.